# GridBagLayout not...behaving

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am sure there is something simple i am missing.  But i am trying to build a simple data entry UI that looks something like this.

[image: screenshot]

Main problem is that i do not like that they all seem to be centered on their columns.  I would like for them to line up on the TextBoxes.  Here is the code.

```
public void makeTextField(int z, int x, int y, String label, JPanel result){
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    JLabel jl = new JLabel();
    jta_array[z] = new JTextArea();
    GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

    gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

    jp.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

    jl.setText(label);
    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 1;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;

    jp.add(jl,gc);

    jta_array[z].setEditable(true);
    jta_array[z].setColumns(30);

    gc.gridx = 2;
    gc.gridy = 1;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;

    jp.add(jta_array[z],gc);

    gc.gridx = x;
    gc.gridy = y;

    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;

    result.add(jp,gc);      
}

public JPanel makePanel() {
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();

    jp.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

    makeTextField(0,1,1,"Project Number:", jp);
    makeTextField(1,1,2,"Project Name:", jp);
    makeTextField(2,1,3,"Author Name:", jp);
    makeTextField(3,2,3,"Author Email:", jp);
    makeTextField(4,3,3,"Author Phone:", jp);
    makeTextField(5,1,4,"Architect/Designer Name:", jp);
    makeTextField(6,2,4,"Architect/Designer Email:", jp);
    makeTextField(7,3,4,"Architect/Designer Phone:", jp);
    makeTextField(8,1,5,"Contractor Name:", jp);
    makeTextField(9,2,5,"Contractor Email:", jp);
    makeTextField(10,3,5,"Contractor Phone:", jp);

    return jp;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Per the answer below.  New Code (in the event anyone else needs to see how it was fixed)

```
public void makeTextField(int z, int x, int y, String label, JPanel result){
    JLabel jl = new JLabel();
    jta_array[z] = new JTextArea();
    GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

    gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

    jl.setText(label);
    gc.gridx = x;
    gc.gridy = y;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;

    result.add(jl,gc);

    jta_array[z].setEditable(true);
    jta_array[z].setColumns(30);

    gc.gridx = x+1;
    gc.gridy = y;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;

    result.add(jta_array[z],gc);

}

public JPanel makePanel() {
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();

    jp.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

    makeTextField(0,1,1,"Project Number:", jp);
    makeTextField(1,1,2,"Project Name:", jp);
    makeTextField(2,1,3,"Author Name:", jp);
    makeTextField(3,3,3,"Author Email:", jp);
    makeTextField(4,5,3,"Author Phone:", jp);
    makeTextField(5,1,4,"Architect/Designer Name:", jp);
    makeTextField(6,3,4,"Architect/Designer Email:", jp);
    makeTextField(7,5,4,"Architect/Designer Phone:", jp);
    makeTextField(8,1,5,"Contractor Name:", jp);
    makeTextField(9,3,5,"Contractor Email:", jp);
    makeTextField(10,5,5,"Contractor Phone:", jp);

    return jp;
}
```

[image: new screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nesting two disparate `GridBagLayout`s. Add your labels and text fields to the same panel so that they are controlled by the same `GridBagLayout`.

Comment: that did it, thanks muchly!  I will modify the above with the resulting code and screenshot